# Loading issues on multi-language React website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multilingual

### Redux Store

I created a redux toolkit store in React. There are reducers in the store which contain the content that will be changed depending on the language, like this:

```
initialState: {
    path: {
        homepage: "Home Page",
        about: "About Us",
    },
    advantages: {
        title: "Advantages"
    },
}
```

### Retrieving Information

Then, in the App.jsx I get the language content from store after checking the current link(checking if it's website.com/en or website.com/)
After I get the data from store, I save it in Context hook and use an Context Provider to pass it through other components.

And in the component I get the data and use it like this:

```
const context = useContext(Language);
....
<h3 className={style.title}>{context?.advantages?.title}</h3>
```

Here, context is the variable that contains the language content

### Problem

I have all thing working.
What I am asking is when I open the website it sometimes does not load the texts right away. And it make it look a bit weird for a while. My internet is good but I am sure when someone with low Internet using it, it will be a problem.

Note: I thought I could make separate components for each language. Like one HomePage for english, one HomePage for second language. In that case I wouldn't need to worry about loading problem, but I thought it wasn't that efficient and clean. So gave up on that idea.

How can I make it load right away?
Or my approach for multi-language website was not right?
If you have a better recommendation, I am open to hear all of them.